# Some confusion about callbacks and .toArray in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, callback, mocha.js

I did some work on an app and was told to go back and figure out why the tests are now failing.  In doing so, I came across some code that started confusing me.

This bit of code is supposed to find a device in the database with a serial number:

```
exports.findBySerial = function (serial, cb) {
  db.devices.find({serial: serial}).toArray((err, count, myDevices) => {
    if (err) {
      return cb(err)
    }
    if (count.length === 0) {
      return cb(null, null)
    } else if (count.length === 1) {
      return cb(null, myDevices[0])
    } else {
      console.error('More than one device with serial no: ' + serial)
      return cb(err)
    }
  })
}
```

The first line uses a different call from the same device repository, `.find`:

```
exports.find = function (search, sort, pagination, cb) {
  const curFind = db.devices.find(search).sort(sort)
  curFind.count((err, count) => {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    if (pagination) {
      curFind.skip((pagination.cp - 1) * pagination.pp).limit(pagination.pp).toArray((err, devices) => {
        if (err) {
          return cb(err)
        } else {
          return cb(null, count, devices)
        }
      })
    } else {
      curFind.toArray((err, devices) => {
        if (err) {
          return cb(err)
        } else {
          return cb(null, count, devices)
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

What confuses me is that the `.find` is supposed to have a callback, which would take null, count, and myDevices.  But in `.findBySerial` the `.find.` call doesn't have a callback.  Instead, `.toArray()` has a callback, but it is returning weird things.  For example, no matter what I do, `count` is returned as an object, whose only property is length and myDevices keeps getting returned as undefined.  But count should be a number, and myDevices should be an array of devices.

At first I thought that my problem might be that the results of `.find` had already been passed through `.toArray()` in `.find` but the docs say that calling `.toArray()` on an array is just like using `slice()`, which means without an argument you will get an exact copy of that array.  So since that is not the problem, I started thinking that it has to do with the missing callback in the `.find` call inside of `.findBySerial`.

I'm confused here.  Can anyone help me?  Is the problem that I'm missing a callback in `.find` and that the callback in `.toArray()` is superfluous, or is something else going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What confuses me is that the .find is supposed to have a callback

`.find` returns a cursor and according to the [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#find) it is **not** supposed to take a callback. Calling `.toArray` results in accessing the cursor and getting the result as an array of documents.

Now, `.toArray` ([docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Cursor.html#toArray)) takes a callback where the first argument is `error` and the second is the `data` (a list of devices in your case). So, in `.findBySerial` what you refer to as `count` is actually an array of devices (if there's no error, of course). And the reason that `count` has `length` is because it is an array.

Comment: Ohh, I see.  I was confusing mongo's `.find()` with my own `exports.find`, which does have a callback.  I think I understand what is happening now.  Thank you.